# Listar somente dados do mesmo id

Tags: php, mysql

Bom galera depois de muito tempo batendo a cabeça com um certo problema eu conseguir resolver ele de uma certa forma (gambiarra) mas agora eu preciso saber como listar dados do meu banco de dados que seja do mesmo id , eu adiciono vários produtos em uma certa venda e eu queria listar esses produtos somente dessa venda , eu tentei usar o while mais ele me retorna uma lista repetida dos valores da minha tabela toda

Meu codigo :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script>

        function alguma(e){
            if(!confirm("Deseja realmente excluir este registro?"))
                cancelOperation(event);
        }
        function cancelOperation(e){
            var evt = e || window.event;
            if(evt.preventDefault())
                evt.preventDefault();
            else
                evt.returnValue = false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<?php
include("banco.php");
echo'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">';
echo'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">';
 include("banco.php");

   $id = $_GET["id"];

        $sql = mysql_query("select * from venda where id_venda='$id'");

        $exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

        $perfil=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venda WHERE id_venda='$id'");

        $dados=list($id_venda,$venda,$data,$placa,$km)=mysql_fetch_row($perfil);

$produtos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto=". $dados[5];
$query = mysql_query($produtos);
$b=mysql_fetch_array($query);
#$id = $b ['id'];
$produtos = $b ['produtos'];


$servicos = "SELECT * FROM servicos WHERE id_servico=". $dados[6];
$query = mysql_query($servicos);
$c=mysql_fetch_array($query);
#$id = $b ['id'];
$servicos = $c ['servicos'];


?>
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>ID DA VENDA :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" readonly="true" name="id" style="width: 170px" value="<?php echo $dados[0]; ?>">

<div id="camp5">
<label for="nome"readonly="true" style="color: #000"><strong>Nº DA VENDA:</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" style="width: 170px" value="<?php echo $dados[1]; ?>">
</div>

<div id="camp1">
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>DATA :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" style="width: 170px" value="<?php echo $dados[2]; ?>">
</div>

<div id="camp6">
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>PLACA :</strong> </label>
    <input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" style="width: 170px" value="<?php echo $dados[3]; ?>">
</div>

<div id="camp2">
<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>KM :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" readonly="true" style="width: 170px" value="<?php echo $dados[4]; ?>">

</div>

<br><br>
<div id="adicionar">
    <a href="adcproduto.php" class="btn btn-info    ">ADICIONAR MAIS PRODUTOS&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/add-icon.png"/></a><br><br>
</div>

<label for="nome" style="color: #000"><strong>PRODUTO :</strong> </label>
<input type="text" name="id" style="width: 450px" readonly="true"  value="<?php echo $produtos; ?>"><br>

<?php
$selbanco = "SELECT * FROM pedido";
$querybanco = mysql_query($selbanco);

$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from pedido where id_venda='$id'");

$exibe1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);

$perfil1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE id_venda='$id'");

$lista=list($id, $produtos , $idvenda)=mysql_fetch_row($perfil1);


?>

<input type="text" name="id" style="width: 450px" readonly="true"  value="<?php echo $lista[1]; ?>"><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Nessa parte eu faço para aparecer os produtos mais so aparece o primeiro , e quando eu tentei com o while ele me retorno todos os dados da tabela, alguem sabe como posso fazer isso ? :

```
<?php
$selbanco = "SELECT * FROM pedido";
$querybanco = mysql_query($selbanco);

$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from pedido where id_venda='$id'");

$exibe1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);

$perfil1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE id_venda='$id'");

$lista=list($id, $produtos , $idvenda)=mysql_fetch_row($perfil1);


?>

<input type="text" name="id" style="width: 450px" readonly="true"  value="<?php echo $lista[1]; ?>"><br>
```

Comment: Não entendi pq é feita duas vezes a mesma consulta(pedido)

Comment: Entao essa e meio que a gambiarra que eu fiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha tem 2 SQLs na mesma tabela no teu exemplo, no meu ver tem duas coisas, ou você usa somente uma tabela para guardar a venda ou deve ter errado no nome da tabela no segundo SQL.
A titulo de exemplo eu guardaria este tipo de transação em pelo menos duas tabelas:

```
tab_vendas
tab_vendas_itens
```

A tabela vendas guarda informações especificas do pedido (ValorTotal, IDCliente, NotaFiscal, etc), ja a itens (CodigoProduto, ValorUnitario, ValorVenda, DescontoItem, Quantidade e etc)

Isso é um exemplo de estrutura para guardar a s informações, mas vamos supor que esteja usando somente uma tabela, no primeiro SQL você deve especificar somente campos que não contenham dados únicos como ID Sequencial da tabela e não "*", aí você usa o DISTINCT para não trazer dados duplicados.